# Interpreting Load Test Results

Tags: asp.net, load-testing, performance-testing

I have inherited an ASP.NET web application (WebForms web site) that performs very badly indeed. A simple look at the code reveals a encyclopedia of how not to write .Net apps (I'm talking string concatenation all over the place, database access inside loops, File I/O in master page_load...etc etc).

Although this application is going to get a major rewrite but I still need make this a bit more robust in the mean-time so I've been doing lots of load testing using LoadUIWeb 2. I have created a very simple scenario that simply logs in and waits on the home page.

I've done a bit of optimisation but I really don't understand the variance on the load test results.

For example, with my simple scenario and 10 virtual users I get results similar to:

Max Page Load - 12.28s
Ave Page Load - 4.26s
Min Page Load - 0.43s

The users do not ramp up and I do not get a nice curve. I see page load times 'randomly' peak and trough. How can the same page take between 0.4s and 12.2s? I would expect to less variance (e.g. always high or always medium etc).

I've done most of the obvious things such as caching,compressing,no debug mode,no tracing etc. I've even tried pre-compiling all to no avail.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The variance really depends on a lot of things. You should **try a really slow ramp up to 10VU over the course of a minute**, to see when the variance really begins to increase dramatically.

Also, you may want to **include server metrics** (from both your database server and your file/web server) to see if it's a specific resource that's causing the delay.

Finally, check the reports 'top 10' and **optimize the slowest routines first** (if you have code or server administration access), as these often act in concert to produce wild and unexpected variances, even at low load.

You can also **contact SmartBear [pre-sales support](http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=LoadUIWebPro)**, and they'll get you in contact with a tech that can help figure out what's really going on here.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Well, LoadUIWeb (asked about in the question) is a SmartBear product: http://loaduiweb.org , so this isn't really promoting their product.

Comment: I have to admit, I missed the reference to LoadUIWeb. Objection dropped, though I still prefer more explicit mention of a user's association with a product. I shouldn't have had to read his profile to determine the relationship.

Comment: Apologies if it sounded like an ad, I highly respect and value being part of the StackOverflow community. When someone asks a question I can help answer, that's what I'll do. I didn't realize being associated with a product or service invalidates one's inputs to be spam by default, a little new to this. I'll be sure to be more explicit in some way next time. Thanks.